# AWS IPSec VPN Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipsec, amazon-vpc, strongswan

I've setup a EC2 instance within my VPC which I use to run a IPSec VPN server using libreswan. I'm able to connect to the VPN server from windows, but once I do so I'm unable to access other EC2 instances within the same VPC which run various other services. I've enabled all traffic on my security group within the VPC, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
JJ

Comment: My setup is similar to the question asked in this post (https://serverfault.com/questions/679391/aws-strongswan-ipsec-vpn) - but I haven't seen any workable solutions thus far.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things you need to do on the EC2 instance to make it work:

1. Make sure it's got **IP Forwarding** turned on.
2. Choose one of these:

   - *either* set up **NAT** of all VPN traffic to the instance IP
   - *or* set up **route** from the VPC subnets to your VPN address range through the EC2 instance and disable *Source / Dest check* in the instance config
3. Use **tcpdump** on both the target EC2 instance and on the EC2 VPN gateway to verify that the VPN traffic is leaving the VPN gateway and is arriving to the target instance.

Hope that helps :)